# Java parse .dat file values for configurable html

Tags: java, html, parsing

I have a the html with a custom php like configuration scheme, and I'm trying to replace the html variables with their corresponding value located in a .dat file. I have managed to store all .dat key value contents in a hashmap however I can't seem to replace the tags without replacing some html, replace a tag because of the space in between or simply nothing is replaced at all. All I want is to replace all the keys with their correspoding value and remove all unused tags. Can someone help me fix this issue? Is their an easier way to do this in Android?

Here is my java code

```
 String replaceDatTags(String html){

        Log.i(TAG, "In replaceDatTags");
        ArrayList<String> tags = new A

rrayList<>(),
            values = new ArrayList<>();
            BufferedReader reader = null;
    
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(mContext.getAssets().open("fullReceipt.dat"), "UTF-8"));
                String line = reader.readLine(); // first tag is the [Values] this one is skiped
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    tags.add(line.substring(0, line.indexOf("=")));
                    values.add(line.substring(line.indexOf("=")+1, line.length())); // get .dat variable value
    
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
            } finally {
                try {
    
                    if (reader != null)
                        reader.close();
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    e2.getMessage();
                }
            }
    
            html = html.replaceAll("\n", "");
            html = html.replaceAll("\t", "");
            html = html.replaceAll("<\\?var ", "");
            html = html.replaceAll("\\?>", "");
            html = html.replaceAll("<\\?ifnexist", "");
            html = html.replaceAll("<!--" , "");
            html = html.replaceAll("-->", "");
            html = html.replaceAll("<\\?ifneq" , "");
            //html = html.replaceAll(" ", "");
    
           for(int i = 0; i < tags.size(); i++){
    
               if(values.get(i).equals("false")){
                   html = html.replace(tags.get(i), "");
               }
    
               else
                    html = html.replace(tags.get(i), values.get(i));
           }
    
            for(int i = 0; i < tags.size(); i++){
    
                html = html.replace(tags.get(i), ""); // delete remaining tags that are floating around
            }
    
            html = html.replaceAll("true", "");
            html = html.replaceAll("false", "");
    
            return html;
```

Html Example

```
   <body style="width: 100%; margin-right: 2px; margin-left: 2px;">
        <div id="header" style="visibility: visible; text-align:center;font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; ">
            <table border="0" style="width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td width="25%"></td>
                    <td width="25%"></td>
                    <td width="25%"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" align="center">
                        <img src="<?var header_logo ?>" width="50%" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
    ....


    <?ifnexist header_user  <!-- ?>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" align="left" style="font-weight: bold;white-space: nowrap">
                        <br>
                        <i>
                            <p> USER:
                                <?var header_user?>
                            </p>
                        </i>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?ifnexist header_user --> ?> 
...

<td align="right" width="45%">
                        <?ifneq header_show_inv_num true <!-- ?>
        

            TRACE:
                    <?var header_trace_nbr?>
                    <?ifneq  header_show_inv_num true --> ?>
                </td>
```

.dat file example

```
[value]
header_logo=data:image/png;base64,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
header_date=10/08/2016
header_time=14:23
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up creating a HTMLBuilder class that builds the receipt by chunks, changed the dat file so it would include HTML chunks and used replace tag and a stringbuilder object to replace with corresponding HTML chunks and constants.

```
private HashMap<String, String> config = getDatTags();
private StringBuilder htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder("");

public String buildReciept(){

        Log.i(TAG, "got dat tags");

        buildHeader();
        buildBody();
        buildFooter();

        return htmlBuilder.toString();
    }
```

how I built the receipt by chunks in buildHeader(), buildBody() and buildFooter() methods

```
 htmlBuilder.append(config.get("IPE_RECEIPTDATA_HEAD"));
 htmlBuilder.replace(htmlBuilder.toString().indexOf("<replace>"),htmlBuilder.toString().indexOf("<replace>")+9 ,config.get("HEADER_MERCHANT_NAME"));
    ...
```

.dat file key value pairs

```
[value]
IPE_RECEIPTDATA_HEAD_LINE_DATA5=<div id="AutCode"><div id="ACODE"><div class="label">
```